# Problemas com openpyxl. Abrir arquivo de Excel com Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando ler um arquivo de Excel mas aparece esta mensagem de erro.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 318
    warn(msg)
UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
<class 'openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook'>

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/edson/PycharmProjects/Projetos/Projeto_10.py", line 7
    wb.get_sheet_names()
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
```

Usando Python3 no Mac

```
#Abrir planilha do Excel

import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('cata_logo.xlsx')
type(wb)
print(type(wb))
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

Comment: Esta dizendo que a função `get_sheet_names` está obsoleta, e está pedindo para utilizar a função `wb.sheetnames`.

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322231/python-2-7-openpyxl-userwarning